# How to modify an XML file specific information using php and generate a new XML

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that is generated by a label printer application, my question is what is the correct way to edit the "pt:data", using SimpleXMLElement or another more efficient way.

```
<pt:body currentSheet="Folha 1" direction="LTR">
<style:sheet name="Folha 1">
<pt:objects>
<barcode:barcode>
<pt:data>text1</pt:data>
</barcode:barcode>
<text:text>
<text:textControl control="FREE" clipFrame="false" aspectNormal="false" shrink="false" autoLF="false" avoidImage="false"/>
<text:textAlign horizontalAlignment="JUSTIFY" verticalAlignment="CENTER" inLineAlignment="BASELINE"/>
<text:textStyle vertical="false" nullBlock="false" charSpace="0" lineSpace="0" orgPoint="6pt" combinedChars="false"/>
<pt:data>text2</pt:data>
<text:stringItem charLen="1"></text:stringItem>
</text:text>
<text:text><pt:data>text3</pt:data></text:text>
</pt:objects></style:sheet>
</pt:body>
```

The goal is to change "text1", "text2" and "text3" to "item1", "item2" and "item3", show the result on the screen and generate a new file with a different name, example: "1edit.xml"

using SimpleXMLElement and registerXPathNamespace I was able to at least display the content on the screen.

```
<?php
$xml=<<<XML
<book xmlns:pt="http://example.org/1">  
    
    <pt:body currentSheet="Folha 1" direction="LTR">
    <style:sheet name="Folha 1">
    <pt:objects>
    <barcode:barcode>
    <pt:data>text1</pt:data>
    </barcode:barcode>
    <text:text>
        <text:textControl control="FREE" clipFrame="false" aspectNormal="false" shrink="false" autoLF="false" avoidImage="false"/>
        <text:textAlign horizontalAlignment="JUSTIFY" verticalAlignment="CENTER" inLineAlignment="BASELINE"/>
        <text:textStyle vertical="false" nullBlock="false" charSpace="0" lineSpace="0" orgPoint="6pt" combinedChars="false"/>
        <pt:data>text2</pt:data>
        <text:stringItem charLen="1"></text:stringItem>
    </text:text>
    <text:text><pt:data>text3</pt:data></text:text>
        </pt:objects></style:sheet>
        </pt:body>
    

</book>
XML;

$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('p', 'http://example.org/1');
$result=$sxe->xpath('//p:data');
foreach ($result as $title)
  {
  echo $title . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

To clarify why XML has this format:

The XML file in question is generated by the system of an industrial machine, altering its structure makes it unreadable by the machine.

The final intention is, through a PHP form with 8 text fields, to execute the function of unzipping a .LBX file, extracting the XLM file from inside, loading, updating as the form data and reassembling the .LBX file with the changed XML inside.

I was able to get PHP to work to unpack the LBX file  (using the ZipArchive class), load and read the XML (using the logic I demonstrated), and recompress the LBX file with the XML inside (using the ZipArchive class). I still haven't been successful with updating the XML while maintaining its original structure. And that's why I came here to ask you all for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Jkp.jpg)

Comment: Why not  to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: Hi Yitzhak Khabinsky, I'm going to look into XSLT. Do you have an example for this scenario I described?

Comment: First, please edit your question, and fix your XML to make it well-formed. It is missing quite a few namespace declarations.

Comment: This XML file is generated by the system of an industrial machine, changing its structure makes it unreadable for the machine.

Comment: In such case, it looks like XML, but it is not XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" sample XML by adding some artificial namespace declarations. It makes it a well-formed XML.

XSLT 1.0 solution is a little bit verbose.

XSLT 2.0 and later, it is just one single line calling a `replace()` function. I put it in the comments.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pt:body currentSheet="Folha 1" direction="LTR" xmlns:pt="ns1" xmlns:style="ns2" xmlns:barcode="ns3" xmlns:text="ns4">
    <style:sheet name="Folha 1">
        <pt:objects>
            <barcode:barcode>
                <pt:data>text1</pt:data>
            </barcode:barcode>
            <text:text>
                <text:textControl control="FREE" clipFrame="false" aspectNormal="false" shrink="false" autoLF="false" avoidImage="false"/>
                <text:textAlign horizontalAlignment="JUSTIFY" verticalAlignment="CENTER" inLineAlignment="BASELINE"/>
                <text:textStyle vertical="false" nullBlock="false" charSpace="0" lineSpace="0" orgPoint="6pt" combinedChars="false"/>
                <pt:data>text2</pt:data>
                <text:stringItem charLen="1"></text:stringItem>
            </text:text>
            <text:text>
                <pt:data>text3</pt:data>
            </text:text>
        </pt:objects>
    </style:sheet>
</pt:body>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:pt="ns1" xmlns:style="ns2" xmlns:barcode="ns3"
                xmlns:text="ns4">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pt:data/text()">
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'text','item')"/>-->
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'text'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'item'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                                    select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no' ?>
<pt:body xmlns:pt="ns1" currentSheet="Folha 1" xmlns:style="ns2" xmlns:barcode="ns3" xmlns:text="ns4" direction="LTR">
  <style:sheet name="Folha 1">
    <pt:objects>
      <barcode:barcode>
        <pt:data>item1</pt:data>
      </barcode:barcode>
      <text:text>
        <text:textControl control="FREE" clipFrame="false" aspectNormal="false" shrink="false" autoLF="false" avoidImage="false"/>
        <text:textAlign horizontalAlignment="JUSTIFY" verticalAlignment="CENTER" inLineAlignment="BASELINE"/>
        <text:textStyle vertical="false" nullBlock="false" charSpace="0" lineSpace="0" orgPoint="6pt" combinedChars="false"/>
        <pt:data>item2</pt:data>
        <text:stringItem charLen="1"/>
      </text:text>
      <text:text>
        <pt:data>item3</pt:data>
      </text:text>
    </pt:objects>
  </style:sheet>
</pt:body>
```